# Java search inside JFrames

Tags: java, jframe

I have following Java code:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setTitle("Sudoku");
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setSize(500, 500);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
frame.getContentPane().add(ruudustik.peaRuudustik()); //returns JPanel with textfields inside
frame.setVisible(true);
```

ruudustik.peaRuudustik function:

```
public static JPanel peaRuudustik() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    for (int i = 0; i < 81; i++) {
        final JTextField ruut = new JTextField();
        ruut.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        ruut.setSize(30, 30);
        ruut.setColumns(1);
        ruut.setName(Integer.toString(i));
        panel.add(ruut);
    }
    return panel;
}
```

How can i change specific textfield value. Every textfield has unique name.

Comment: Textfield? Where? Please post more code.

Comment: You can try using the [getComponents()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponents()) mehtod - however, I'd discourage doing so. It is quite problemmatic and volatile what/how you can access those textfields. Simply keep a reference (for a Sudoku, a 2D array for the references is perfect).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate over panel subcomponents, but I recommend another approach - use a `Map`, for example:

```
Map<Integer, JComponent> textFields = new HashMap<Integer, JTextField>();
...
textFields.put(i, ruut);
ruut.setName(Integer.toString(i));
panel.add(ruut);
```

Then, access the components simply by `textFields.get(id);`

Comment: rlegendi's approach might be even better, unless the number of text fields is variable OR text field identifiers are not of type int

Answer (score 0):

As the `JTextField` name is an integer-based string, the easiest way to access them would be to use an array of fields like so:

```
JTextField[] myTextFields = new JTextField[81];
for (int i = 0; i < myTextFields.length; i++) {
   myTextFields[i] = new JTextField();
   myTextFields[i].setName(Integer.toString(i));
   ...
}
```